# Taking sum ini spark-scala based on a condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame like this. How can i take the sum of the column sales where the rank is greater than 3 , per 'M'

```
+---+-----+----+
|  M|Sales|Rank|
+---+-----+----+
| M1|  200|   1|
| M1|  175|   2|
| M1|  150|   3|
| M1|  125|   4|
| M1|   90|   5|
| M1|   85|   6|
| M2| 1001|   1|
| M2|  500|   2|
| M2|  456|   3|
| M2|  345|   4|
| M2|  231|   5|
| M2|  123|   6|
+---+-----+----+
```

Expected Output --

```
+---+-----+----+---------------+
|  M|Sales|Rank|SumGreaterThan3|
+---+-----+----+---------------+
| M1|  200|   1|            300|
| M1|  175|   2|            300|
| M1|  150|   3|            300|
| M1|  125|   4|            300|
| M1|   90|   5|            300|
| M1|   85|   6|            300|
| M2| 1001|   1|            699|
| M2|  500|   2|            699|
| M2|  456|   3|            699|
| M2|  345|   4|            699|
| M2|  231|   5|            699|
| M2|  123|   6|            699|
+---+-----+----+---------------+
```

I have done sum over ROwnumber like this

```
df.withColumn("SumGreaterThan3",sum("Sales").over(Window.partitionBy(col("M"))))` //But this will provide total sum of sales.
```

To replicate the same DF-

```
val df = Seq(
("M1",200,1),
("M1",175,2),
("M1",150,3),
("M1",125,4),
("M1",90,5),
("M1",85,6),
("M2",1001,1),
("M2",500,2),
("M2",456,3),
("M2",345,4),
("M2",231,5),
("M2",123,6)
).toDF("M","Sales","Rank")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the partition is enough to set the `window` function. Of course you also have to use the conditional summation by mixing `sum` and `when`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w = Window.partitionBy("M")
df.withColumn("SumGreaterThan3", sum(when('Rank > 3, 'Sales).otherwise(0)).over(w).alias("sum")).show
```

This will givs you the expected results.